# How can I find the cause of this intermittent failure / null response from Shopify API when checking inventory levels

Tags: php, api, shopify

While Using a php library (https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify) to access the Shopify API I am *occasionally* getting a `Code 520` response from a call to the API endpoint to check inventory levels of a Product / Variants at a specific location. I'm aware that code 520 is Cloudflare notifying me that it got a failed or empty response from the server, I am seeking to understand the cause of the failure.

In general (aside from these occasional failures) the API responses are working well. The call fails at approximate rate of 1 in 1000 calls (but not with a regular interval, but of that order of magnitude). Note: If I log the specifics of the call and manually recreate that exact request it works fine, so it does not seem to be the structure of the call or the payload etc.

Failure response is like this:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PHPShopify\Exception\CurlException: Request failed with HTTP Code 520. in /var/www/html/vendor/phpclassic/php-shopify/lib/ShopifyResource.php:489 Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/phpclassic/php-shopify/lib/ShopifyResource.php(315): PHPShopify\ShopifyResource->processResponse(NULL, 'inventory_level...') 
#1 /var/www/html/invconnect/const_inventorypull_shopify.php(308): PHPShopify\ShopifyResource->get(Array) 
#2{main}thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/phpclassic/php-shopify/lib/ShopifyResource.php on line 489
```

Looks like there is a NULL response coming from an inventory level check, the check in question is formed like this:

```
$params = array([inventory_item_ids] => "3439123438412, 34399123471552, 34399412304023", [location_ids] => "31741235383");

$result= $shopify->InventoryLevel->get($params);
```

This request is running well for many hundreds of items, and then it will give the response above - any idea how I can debug this or what might be causing it?

The request is rate limited to 1 every 0.6s so should not be a rate limit issue (as leaky bucket allowance allows for 2 requests per second so I should never be depleting allowance).

Comment: Not sure what caused the immediate down vote but if there is a way I can improve my question please let me know

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#Cloudflare

Comment: @maio290 - I'm familiar with 520 being a Cloudflare catchall for failed server response, my question is asking how can I diagnose the issue / understand the cause of the failed server response.